# Advanced Taxonomy query, with 3 post types

Tags: php, wp-query, loop

I'm been trying to figure out how to do this for a few hours now and Have final given in to asking for help.

I've got 3 custom post types that I need to query for a term called home which is inside a taxonomy on each one.

hope I've been clear with what I want to achieve, here is the code I'm using at the moment.

```
            <?php
          $args = array(
        'post_type' => array( 'testimonial', 'casestudy', 'post'),
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
        'tax_query' => array (
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
        'taxonomy' => 'testimonial_category',
        'terms' => 'home'
        'field' => 'slug'
        ),
        array(
        'taxonomy' => 'casestudy_category',
        'terms' => 'home'
        'field' => 'slug'
        ),
        array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'terms' => 'home'
        'field' => 'slug'
        ),
        )
);

        $query = new WP_Query( $args );
        $postcount = 0;
            ?>
           <?php if ($query->have_posts()) : ?>
           <?php while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>
           <?php $postcount++; ?>
```

Comment: There is a missing comma after each `'terms' => 'home'`. Does correcting that fix it?

Comment: I actually managed to fix this now, using the following code 'terms' => array('home'), placing an array around the term slug. the comma was a small typo thanks for pointing it out s_ha_dum.

Answer (score 0):

to make this work all I did was add

```
'terms' => array('home'),
```

to each term like this above

`'terms => 'home'`

Comment: I thought "home" was your `slug_name`. `terms` should accept an integer, string, or array.

Comment: it depends what you pass in the fields => 'id/slug'

Comment: Yes, but you missed the point. Your original code has `'terms => 'home',`. your solution is `'terms => array('slug_name'),` which is confusing. Are you saying the fix was to use `'terms => array('home'),`?

Comment: I've amended my mistake, thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: `terms => 'home'` and `terms => array('home')` are equivalent as far as this query is concerned. It processes either a string or an array. You may have solved it but this is not that fix.